# Differentiate between HTML form SUBMIT and Console based form SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, spam, console.log

I have a website `www.abc.com` which has a page `xyz.php`. `xyz.php` takes a form submit event reads the data and saves in the database.

`www.abc.com` has a form with action on `xyz.php`. Now I can use console to send the same request without actually posting it from the HTML form.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'www.abc.com/xyz.php',
    data:{
        "key1" : 'value1',
        "key2" : 'value2'
    },
    success: function( textStatus, jqXHR,response) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(textStatus,jqXHR , errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```

I wonder how to validate on server side whether the data fetched is actually a user submit from the HTML form or was from a console.

And how to stop users from posting from the console input.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Blender: Actually if I frame the above `ajax` code within a `for` loop then it can be used for abusing the website. Therefore, I should know whether it was coming from the actual form submit or somewhere else.? How to differentiate between that.?

Comment: In simple Words `How to Prevent DOS(Denial of Service) attack` ? :)

Comment: @VedantTerkar: is there any way to programatically implement it on server side.?

Comment: I Personally Think `Captcha` Is your Best Friend. but I've found something Useful: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790005/how-to-prevent-automated-ajax-attacks). Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @VedantTerkar: But for registered user it is quite annoying for anyone to actually fill the CAPTCHA everytime he/she post. And if one of the registered user is doing this, before I block him/her the lost is already done.

Comment: Here is one way: Use `timestamp`. On each request check the Previous `timestamp` and if you think that `User` is posting too many `POST's` in short `timestamp difference` Then probably the `user` is `bot` and then and only then you can tell him/her  to answer the `captcha` You can maintain previous `timestamp` in `session` and can `update` it time to time (`per request`).

Comment: @VedantTerkar: I already thought of it. But, I bypassed it. I am sending the automated posts after the threshold timing. And the attack succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

An HTTP request is an HTTP request and a manually constructed one can look however the user wants it to (so while you can shove hidden fields, cookies and so on into the requirements for a request, they can always be replicated manually).

Use authentication/authorization and worry about *who* is sending the data, not *what*.

Comment: Then I can abuse any website I want. If I write the same piece of code within a for loop it will be posted infinite times. But the data is irrelevant. then how to know whether it is coming from my page or it is coming from somewhere else.?

Comment: Yes (at which point they'll start using rate limiters or just block your IP) but there the problem is "many requests" not "requests sent without using the code on the page" and they still wouldn't be detecting the tool used. You cannot tell if it is coming from your page or "somewhere else". You can tell if it is coming from [a third party redirecting someone else to your site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) though.